# useEffect does not work when the array it depends on is empty

Tags: reactjs

I have a website with a shopping cart. And I have an useEffect that updates the subtotal according to the products in the cart array. The useEffect works when I delete one of the items in the cart. However, whenever the products in the cart run out, it does not work, and the subtotal is not calculated again.

This is my delete item function:

```
const handleDeleteProduct = () => {
    setCart((element) => element.filter(element => element.item.id !== item.item.id))
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
}
```

And this is the useEffect:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        handleSubTotal(countSubTotal())    
    }, [cart])
```

I could not understand why the last product can be deleted, or affects the state of useEffect

Comment: Did you check if useEffect is really not called and the problem is not in handleSubTotal or countSubTotal?

Comment: yes, when I print something with console.log in useEffect it also does not work.

Comment: Son product silindiği zaman useEffect çalışıyor da ondan daha sonra yaptığın başka işlemlerde (mesela addproduct) mi çalışmıyor?

Comment: Hayır, mesela 3 product var cart arrayi içinde, 1. Yi siliyorum siliniyor ve useEffect çalışıyor, 2. Yi siliyorum, siliniyor ve useEffect çalışıyor, 3. Yü siliyorum siliniyor fakat useEffect çalışmıyor.

Comment: Why did you switch language? Now I'm unable to follow :) @TahaTüzgen how do you know when a product run out? Do you have to make a request to your back end?

Comment: Sorry for the language, I said in my last comment, if I had 3 products in the cart array, and I delete one, it is deleted and useEffect works. When I delete the second one, it is deleted, and the useEffect works. However, when I deleted the last one, it is deleted but the useEffect is not activated.

Comment: If you are deleting each time with the same `handleDeleteProduct` there is no reason it wouldn't work. Maybe it's already working, it depends on what `handleSubTotal` and `countSubTotal` are doing. To be sure add a `console.log("hi")` before `handleSubTotal(countSubTotal())` in your `useEffect`.

Comment: I tried console.log before handleSubTotal in the useEffect, and it didn't print anything, that is why I cannot understand the problem.

Comment: Can you make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please, by adding all the relevant code? One thing I can already tell is that calling `localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart))` right after `setCart((element) => element.filter(element => element.item.id !== item.item.id))` you registering in the storage `cart` from the last render, not the just filtered one, as a re-render is needed for that.